# Does Google Analytics report multiple tabs?

Tags: google-analytics

Visitors to a site may have several pages open at once using multiple tabs or windows.

Does Google Analytics provide any info on this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked, using the new (beta) [real-time feature](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html) in Google Analytics, opening a site I manage in two tabs within a single browser, and: No. It does register the multiple page loads, but only one active user the entire time. Which makes obvious sense, as this would be part of it determining visitors vs. raw viewcounts.

Opening the site in entirely separate *browsers* did show multiple visitors, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Google can tell you if a person open your website from a new tab or a new windows. By the way, I can't think how this info can be usefull

Comment: I will often middle-click to open a link in a new tab to read later. It may be a while before I actually view the page, but I think that Google Analytics would have began counting the view time from when the page was loaded. Therefore 'time on site' is off. Also, I would like to better analyse how user's move through a site using tabs.

Comment: How can Google tell you have multiple tabs open? Any source/evidence for this?

Comment: It would be possible if every page pinged Google every N seconds.

Comment: Chartbeat repeatedly pings, so they could tell but they don't.